# Resharper telling me to use auto with const

Tags: c++, resharper, constants, auto

In my program, resharper is telling me that I should use auto whenever I initialize a const value, such as the int charSize I declared. Why should I use auto instead of an int when I know that I want that to be a integer, not any other datatype because I won't ever change that value from the int type. Is it more efficient to use the auto type instead of a direct type?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int charSize = 256;

    char str[charSize];

    scanf_s("%256s", str, charSize);

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact text? This seems ludicrously wrong/buggy/silly, whether it's really trying to get you to switch to type deduction or is going on about now-removed storage class specifiers for some reason.

Comment: From what I remember non `constexpr` values are not allowed in array declaration. Is it an extension or am I missing something?

Comment: @Incomputable: A `const` object initialised with a constant-expression counts, although it may need to be `static` too (can't remember)

Comment: So out of curiosity, is it recommending you do something like: `auto charSize = 256`, or `const auto charSize = 256`?

Comment: It tells me to use auto, don't know whether it wants me to just use auto or not but I have to use the const, otherwise my char array won't accept charSize. [Image](http://prntscr.com/f5iyrt)

Comment: You are basically asking when one should use `auto`. But that's a very broad question with quite some different expert opinions. What we can tell you is that 1.) ReSharper is not authorative and also just expresses someone's opinion on this, and 2.) No, efficiency is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Again, show us the exact text.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition http://prntscr.com/f5jcmx

Comment: Okay, that doesn't match what you've told us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "auto type". Writing `auto` since C++11 enables type deduction, so the object would still be an `int` but your compiler would have figured that out for you.

In this example, there is no benefit to that whatsoever; in fact, simply being clear and writing the type you want is (IMO) far superior. If it's not simply buggy<sup>†</sup>, Resharper is overstepping its bounds in trying to make that decision for you.

<sub><sup>†</sup> It's possible that Resharper is confused, and trying to get you to use the `auto` *storage class specifier* (removed in C++11), though even for `const` objects this was always the default at block scope.</sub>

Comment: Maybe they are trying to stop bugs like `const int foo = 2147483648;`

Comment: @NathanOliver: Maybe. But I don't see what `const` has to do with that example, really

Comment: True,  That happens if it is `const` or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'm new to C++. What is the bug in `const int foo = 2147483648`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: NVM. Understood.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper simply allows to change an explicit type to `auto`, it does not want you or tell you to do that. Please note that the severity of the "Use auto" inspection is set to "Hint" by default, meaning that it won't show on the error stripe bar, but still leaves you an option to invoke the corresponding quick fix should you want to use `auto` for some reason. If you never want to see this inspection, just set its severity to "Do not show" via the inspection context menu.